# Can't get through Jest pre-flight check (React)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-scripts

I'm getting stuck running yarn test for the first time (there are not really any tests except the default)
[image]

I've done steps 1-6 but it still doesn't fix the  message
for step 7, when I run `npm ls jest` I get

[image]

it says in the message "This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed jest." -- however, npm shows there is no other jest installed or active, only the one as a dependency from react-scripts. how should I interpret this information and where do I go from here?

Comment: Do you have `jest` listed in your `package.json` as dependency ?

Comment: I found it, it was in the `node_moduldes/` directory one level up from the client/ directory (where the tests run)

Comment: try using `yarn remove` to avoid having extraneous dependencies or running `yarn install` after modifying `package.json`

Comment: Posting the actual error instead of screenshots will be much more helpful, because your question will be indexed by the search engines

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it was in the node_moduldes/ directory one level up from the client/ directory (where the tests run)

[image]